# How to add just one label per x variable level to a dodged barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am representing the frequencies of some variable levels by group in a dodged barplot. In addition, I would like to add the difference of these frequencies by group on top of the bars (this difference is already stored in difference variable on the dataframe).

This is the original dataframe and the code to plot it:

```
test<-data.frame(color=c('green', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue','red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green'),
                 group=c('A','A','B','A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 difference=c('0','-1','-1','-1','-4','-4','-4','-4','-4','-4','0'))


ggplot(data=test, aes(x=color, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

What I would like to get is the following:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkK1l.png)

I am trying something like:

```
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=color, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
   geom_text(aes(stat='identity',label=difference), vjust=2)
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially with your pre-computed labels I would suggest to compute your counts outside of `ggplot` which makes it easier to set the `y` position for the labels. Additionally I use `distinct` in `geom_text` to place only one label on top of the bars:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

test |>
  group_by(color, group) |>
  summarise(n = n(), difference = unique(difference)) |>
  mutate(y_label = max(n)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = n)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = group), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    data = ~ distinct(.x, color, y_label, difference),
    aes(y = y_label, label = difference), vjust = 0, nudge_y = .25
  )
```

[image]